# If the product and the sum of two complex numbers are real, what can we say about the numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> If the product and the sum of two complex numbers are real, what can we say about the numbers? Prove it.

Explanation will be very helpful. Actually the question asks for a proof. Hence, a proof is all that we need. I actually am quite confused with it. I have proved a lot more complex questions in complex numbers and this little proof blocked my brain. Please stop this block.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about two general complex numbers, $a + bi$ and $c + di$.  What is their product and their sum?  What are necessary constraints on a, b, c, and d that allow for the product and the sum to be real?

Answer (score 3):

Let the two complex numbers be $z = x + iy$ and $w = u + iv$.
Then, calculate $zw$ and $z+w$ and set the imaginary parts to zero.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ and $b$ are your two numbers, they are the roots of the equation
$$
(x-a)(x-b)=0
$$
which can also be written as
$$
x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0
$$

The problem conditions mean that this is a quadratic equation with *real* coefficients. What does that tell you about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I don't understand what you get if you establish this polynomial equation?

Comment: Roots of polynomials with real coefficients are either real or they come in pairs of conjugate numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$$z_1=a+ib$$
$$z_2=c+id$$

We demand that $z_1+z_2$ and $z_1 \cdot z_2$ is real. If we assume that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are non-real, we have

$$a+ib+c+id=(a+c)+i(b+d) \implies b=-d.$$

$$(a+ib)(c+id)=(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc) \implies ad=-bc\implies a=c.$$

You can therefore write $$z_2=a-bi,$$

which is the complex conjugate of $z_1$.

Comment: You should have that $a + ib + c + id = (a + c) + i\mathbf{(b+d)}$, not $(a + c) + i(b + c)$, and so we have that $b = -d$ instead of $b = -c$.

Comment: @Dylan Thank you! Going in I also expected to get the conjugate.. I guess I trust my afternoon calculation skills way too much :)

Comment: 0 and 1 sum/multiply to a real result, but are not complex conjugate...

Comment: This answer is missing the general solution $b=d=0$ (with $a \ne c$).

Comment: @TonyK Thank you for your comment. I've edited my answer accordingly, although I haven't calculated the case, as I suspect that was not the intention of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two complex numbers $q$ and $p$ such that,$q=c+id$ and $p=a+ib$.
A.T.Q.  $pq$ is real and $p+q$ real
 $$pq=(ac-bd)+(bc+ad)i$$ 
since pq is real, the imaginary part must be zero,hence bc+ad=0
or $$bc=-ad$$
then
$$p+q=(a+c)+(b+d)i$$ here also $b+d$ must  be zero or $$d=-b$$
So putting $d=-b$ in $bc=-ad$, you will get,$$b(c-a)=0$$
So either
$$b=d=0$$
or $$a=c, b=-d$$.

So either $p$ and $q$ are conjugated $$p=a+bi,q=a-bi$$
or both are real
$$p=a,q=c$$

Comment: why a downvote??

Comment: This answer is basically unreadable. Use Mathjax to express your answers symbolically, and space things properly. Also, 0 and 1 sum and multiply to real results but are not complex conjugates!

Comment: Also: $z$ and $p$? Why??

Comment: p because i cant't write 1 and 2 in subscript.

Comment: but sorry guys i should have expressed it properly its my fault.

Comment: I changed the first three expression to Mathjax (adding the \$ signs). I think you can imagine how to do the remaining expression. If you click the left mouse button over a math expresion you can select "Show Math as >  TeX commands". Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Semiclassical It is very strict to downvote the first answer  of a user because it does not use mathjax.

Comment: If both are imaginary, then the only way for their sum to be real is if they're actually complex conjugate. (i.e. $i$ and $-i$ satisfy the stated conditions but not $i$ and $-2i$.)

Comment: so what is my fault, i couldn't get you !semiclassical

Comment: You claim that either $p$ and $q$ are conjugate, or both are real, or both are imaginary. I'm saying that the last option doesn't actually work. (The first two are fine.)

Comment: i don't say that someone has edited it, i m gonna remove it

Comment: your explaination for last one is correct and i also disagree with last statement

Answer (score 1):

you will have $$z_1+z_2=a,z_1\cdot z_2=b$$, setting $$z_1=x+iy,z_2=u+iv$$ then we get $$y+v=0$$ and $$yu+vx=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Seems no answer was accepted yet. Try this luck...
The product of two reals can be expressed by the complex quantities by
\begin{align}
\Re\{z_1\}\Re\{z_2\}&=\frac{1}{2}\Re\{z_1\}(z_2+z_2^\ast)=\frac{1}{2}\Re\{z_1z_2\}+\frac{1}{2}\Re\{z_1z_2^\ast\}    ..........(1)
\end{align}
Let's show the relationship (1) with any arbitrary  (complex) quantities $z_1=Ae^{i\omega_it}$ and $z_2=Be^{i\omega_jt}$, then
\begin{align}
\Re{\{Ae^{i\omega_it}\}}\Re{\{Be^{i\omega_jt}\}}&=\frac{1}{4}{\left\{(Ae^{i\omega_it}+A^*e^{-i\omega_it})(Be^{i\omega_jt}+B^*e^{-i\omega_jt})\right\}}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{1}{4}{\left\{ABe^{i\omega_{ij}^+t}+A^*B^*e^{-i\omega_{ij}^+t}+AB^*e^{i\omega_{ij}^-t}+A^*Be^{-i\omega_{ij}^-t}\right\}}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{1}{4}{\left\{ABe^{i\omega_{ij}^+t}+(ABe^{i\omega_{ij}^+t})^*+AB^*e^{i\omega_{ij}^-t}+(AB^*e^{i\omega_{ij}^-t})^*\right\}}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Re{\left\{ABe^{i\omega_{ij}^+t}+AB^*e^{i\omega_{ij}^-t}\right\}}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Re{\left\{(Ae^{i\omega_{i}})(Be^{i\omega_{j}t}+B^*e^{-i\omega_{j}t})\right\}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Re{\left\{Q_{ij}^+e^{i\omega_{ij}^+t}\right\}}+\frac{1}{2}\Re{\left\{Q_{ij}^-e^{i\omega_{ij}^-t}\right\}}
\end{align}
where $\omega_{ij}^+=\omega_i+\omega_j$ and $\omega_{ij}^-=\omega_i-\omega_j$. It can be seen that $AB=BA=Q_{ij}^+=Q_{ji}^+$ and $AB^*=(A^*B)^\ast=Q_{ij}^-=Q_{ji}^{-*}$

Answer (score -1):

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be these copmlex numbers.

As their sum is real, we can write $z_1 = a + bi,\,z_2 = c - bi$ for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

The product $z_1 z_2 = (a + bi) (c - bi) = ac + b^2 + b(c-a)i$ is real. Then $b(c-a) = 0$.

So $z_1$ and $z_2$ are conjugative (and, maybe, even real ones).

Comment: 0,1 aren't conjugate but satisfy the stated conditions.

Comment: I've told they may just be real both

Comment: If that's what you intended, the wording of that last line is confusing . What would be valid is: Either $z_1$ and $z_2$ are conjugate, or they are both real.

Comment: thanks, @Semiclassical, that's right

Answer (score -3):

If $r$ and $s$ are your complex numbers then the polynomial $(z-r)(z-s) = z^2-(r+s)z +rs$.  The coefficients are the sum and product and must be real.  So the polynomial is of the form $z^2+az+b$ with $a$ and $b$ real.   If you set it equal to zero, and solve, the roots (which are $r$ and $s$) must be conjugates.

Comment: $0$ and $1$ are not conjugate, but they satisfy the stated conditions.

Comment: Um...yes they are.  But I'll remove the word "complex".

Comment: @B.Goddard Two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ are conjugate iff $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=a-bi$ for some real $a, b$. $0$ and $1$ definitely are not conjugate (note that the conjugate of a real number is just itself).

Comment: If you meant that the set of roots $\{z_1,z_2\}$ is preserved under complex conjugation, that's fine. I read it instead as $r$ and $s$ being conjugate to each other (which needn't be true).

Comment: @NoahSchweber  There are other types of "conjugates".  $3+\sqrt{2}$ and $3-\sqrt{2}$ are conjugates.  Solutions to quadratic equations are conjugates of each other, even if the surd is degenerate.

Comment: @Semiclassical  You're using too narrow a definition of "conjugate."

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/